# Extracting partial residuals from effects package for a linear mixed effects model with an interaction term

Tags: r, lme4

I’m running a linear mixed effects model with an interaction term.

```
library(lme4)
library(effects)
data<-mtcars
model<-lme4::lmer(mpg~cyl + hp*gear+ disp + (1|carb), REML=T, data=data)

# The partial residuals appear on the default effect() plot
plot(effect("hp:gear",partial.residuals=TRUE, model))

# But partial residual values are not included when saving as a dataframe
residuals <- as.data.frame(effect("hp:gear",partial.residuals=TRUE, model))
```

Any idea how to extract the partial residuals for a LMEM with interaction term from effects()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run the modeling code in the question. Then, save the output of function `effects`.

```
eff <- effect("hp:gear", partial.residuals = TRUE, model)
```

Now, `resid(eff)` gives the residuals. Since the question asks for the *partial* residuals, go look for them:

```
grep("resid", names(eff))
#[1] 12 13

names(eff)[grep("resid", names(eff))]
#[1] "residuals"               "partial.residuals.range"
```

And use the second name to extract the list member `"partial.residuals.range"`.

```
eff$partial.residuals.range
#[1] 10.4 33.9
```

For all the partial residuals, they are defined as

```
predict(model) + resid(model)

range(predict(model) + resid(model))
#[1] 10.4 33.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This solution works to get the range of partial residuals but it does not seem possible to get all of the partial residual observations as they are shown on the default plot : plot(effect("hp:gear",partial.residuals=TRUE, model))

Answer (score 2):

The partial residuals are computed by the `plot()` method, not by `Effect()`, because it's necessary to know which points are in each panel, information that's available to a panel function in a **lattice** plot, before computing the partial residuals.

The method used is described in J. Fox and S. Weisberg (2018), "Visualizing Fit and Lack of Fit in Complex Regression Models with Predictor Effect Plots with Partial Residuals," [*Journal of Statistical Software* 87:9, 1–27](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v87/i09/) (which is referenced in `?Effect`).